# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to select a `row` in my `C1TrueDBGrid` with respect to the text entered in the `textbox` using `linq`.

The sample code is given below

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewRow) = _  
          From row As DataGridViewRow In grdDistricts.Rows _  
          Where row.Cells("Taluk").Value.ToString().Equals(TextBox1.Text) _  
          Select row
```

Getting error in the code below

```
For Each r As DataGridViewRow In query
    r.Selected = True
Next
```

Error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow

Comment: `For Each r As DataRow In query` ?  What's your problem?  You can't randomly cast objects of type A to B unless B is an ancestor of A...

Comment: @Will i tried this by referencing [this](http://www.bitsbyta.com/2011/01/searching-in-datagridview-through-linq_12.html) article

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with my question.  You cannot randomly cast objects of one type to unrelated objects of another type.  That's the error you're getting.  The solution is similar to the problem of you hitting yourself in the head with a hammer:  Don't do it.

Comment: @Will so do have any suggestions for my problem `am trying to select row in my C1TrueDBGrid with respect to the text entered in the textbox using linq` ??

Comment: No idea what `C1TrueDBGrid` is or what type `grdDistricts` is, so nobody can help you with the code you're showing.  Look at your C1TrueDBGrid instance, find the rows property that has instances of type DataGridViewRow, then look through them and select the one you want.  If that's even possible for that C1WhateverNeverSeenItBeforeGrid.

Comment: @will so you must [see this](https://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/TrueDBGridWinForms/)

Comment: According to the docs, the Rows property of the C1TrueDBGrid is just a `System.Data.DataRowsCollection`.  So instead of using `DataGridViewRow`, just use `DataRow`.  Your exception message suggests this as well.